# Trigger option to set specific build parameters?

Tags: teamcity, teamcity-7.0

I'm looking for a way to attach some specific build parameter to a scheduled trigger.

The idea is that we are continuously building debug versions of our products. Our nightly build has to be a release build, though. The build configurations for most of our projects is absolutely the same. It even has a configuration parameter, already. So all I would need is a trigger which allows for specifying an override for a single build parameter. That would cut the build configurations to maintain by half.

Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Not right now, you can follow [this issue](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/TW-6439).

Answer (score 6):

The approach I use is to create a "Deploy :: Dev D1 :: Run all integration tests" build. I then create a build trigger on each integration service build.

I create a parameter called "env:OctopusEnvironment" for integration service build. Set the value to be empty. I like to use prompt and display:

```
select display='prompt' label='OctopusEnvironment' data_13='Production' data_12='CI' data_11='Local - Hassan' data_10='Local - Mustafa' description='OctopusEnvironment' data_02='Test T1' data_01='Dev D1' data_04='Local - Taliesin' data_03='Continuous Deployment CI 1' data_06='Local - Paulius' data_05='Local - Ravi' data_08='Local - Venkata' data_07='Local - Marko' data_09='Local - Ivan'
```

In each integration service build I add this powershell step:

```ps
$octopusEnvironment = ($env:OctopusEnvironment).Trim()

Write-Host "Octopus environment = '$octopusEnvironment'"
if ($octopusEnvironment.Length -lt 1) {
    Write-Host "Auto detecting octopus environment"
    $trigger = '%teamcity.build.triggeredBy%' -split '::'
    if ($trigger.Length -gt 2){
        $environment = $trigger[1].Trim()
        Write-Host "##teamcity[setParameter name='env.OctopusEnvironment' value='$environment']"
    }
}
```

So now I can run the integration test via a trigger and when I run it directly it will prompt me on which environment to run integration test against.

Comment: Nice little powershell suff. But that can't be an excuse for JetBrains guys for not having this feature in Teamcity itself.

Answer (score 4):

I was stuck with the same problem and voted for the issue mentioned by Evgeny. One solution we thought, as mentioned sergiussergius, was to add a final step in the build-steps sequence to trigger manually the next build-configuration by passing custom-build parameters using the REST API. But in this case, we are loosing the build-chain information.
Using TeamCity 9.x, trying some stuff on the REST API, I could implement a solution who makes it possible to retrieve the triggering (ancestor) build and its parameters from the triggered (child) build.
The first thing we do is getting the current build using the environment variables set by TeamCity:

```
https://<host>/httpAuth/app/rest/builds/number:<env.BUILD_NUMBER>,buildType:(name:<env.TEAMCITY_BUILDCONF_NAME>,project:<env.TEAMCITY_PROJECT_NAME>)
```

In the response from the REST API, we have a */build/triggered* tag which contains information about the trigger. It looks like this

```
<triggered type="unknown" details="##triggeredByBuildType='<triggering-build-configuration-internalId>' triggeredByBuild='<triggering-build-number>'" date="20160105T190642+0700"/>
```

The  looks like *btxxx* for us.
From it, we can access the triggering-build (ancestor) using the following request to the REST API:

```
https://<host>/httpAuth/app/rest/builds/number:<triggering-build-number>'4,buildType:(internalId:<triggering-build-configuration-internalId>1,project:name:<env.TEAMCITY_PROJECT_NAME>)
```

from the response, we can get the ancestor-build's parameters values, and set it in the current build using:

```
echo "##teamcity[setParameter name='env.ENV_AAA' value='aaaaaaaaaa']")
```

Notes:

- this post reference TeamCity version 7.X. I did this using TeamCity version 9.X, and could not try it with a previous version. I don't know if the REST API calls mentioned in my post are similar in the previous versions.
- In this solution, the ancestor's build-configuration (the one who trigger the build) and the child's build-configuration (the one triggered) are in the same project. I did not do the test using build-configurations in 2 different projects: I would expect the "trigger" tag to provide information about the ancestor's project. It would be nice if someone could do the test.

I hope this solution may help!

Comment: The built-in feature to set custom parameters on automatic build triggering is, apparently, coming in the next release (after being on-hold for "only" 12 years). In the meantime, your solution did help a lot! Thanks, man. Very neat workaround, indeed.

Answer (score 2):

This is not a general solution, but in certain cases (for example if you want to determine whether the build was started by a schedule trigger or some other method), a workaround is to examine the predefined parameter `teamcity.build.triggeredBy`.

This parameter is set to the same string that is shown on the build's overview page next to the label "Triggered by:". For example, "Schedule Trigger", "Git", or a user's full name. (There is also a `teamcity.build.triggeredBy.username` parameter, but it is only set in the latter case).

The limitation of this approach is that you cannot, for example, distinguish between two separate schedule triggers defined for the same build configuration. But in that case you could resort to examining the current time as well.

Answer (score 1):

I added request to last build step

```
curl -i -u "%login%:%pass%" -H "Content-type: text/plain" -X PUT -d "v1" http://tc.server/httpAuth/app/rest/buildTypes/id:%buildConfigurationId%/parameters/env.%SOME_PARAMETER%
```

http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD8/REST+API